# How do I put multiple items on the same line in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, layout, adapter

I have an ArrayList of items that are linked to a custom Adapter.  The items are in alphabetical order.  I would like my ListView to have a maximum of four items on each line of the ListView with the lines separated alphabetically.

For example:

[ Hi ] [ Hospital ] [ Hotel ] [ HotSpot ]

[ House ]

[ Impossible] [ Improbable ]

So multiple items would be on the same line of the ListView.

Is there a way to use the position variable within the custom Adapter class's getView() method to accomplish this?

Here is an example, sorry for the quality:
[image: People Screen]

In the image, the backing store, such as ArrayList, would contain those names alphabetized.

Comment: Please check this [article](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) and [also this](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html) there are many more available on Internet just search and you will find better and better.

Comment: hey, are you found any solution to do thiss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to implement the CustomListView. on GetView method of the ArrayAdapter of your object.

See below Example:

[See this link](http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx).

It will realy going to help you.

Enjoy.  :)

Comment: In that example, people's names are displayed from a top to bottom order.  It's a good example and I'm trying to find a way to group alphabetically.  For example, people with the last name Albert would be on one line (up to 4 people).  So not just one backing item per row, but up to four.

Comment: Will you please put any rough Screen Shot of it ?

Comment: @benkdev: you should have to sort the data as you want before to displaying it in to the ListView. After getting sort the data you will get your desire data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the getView( ) method one of the parameters is a position which can be used to send the relevant view back

```
public abstract View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Comment: If the backing store has many items, and is linked to an adapter, the getView of the adapter will return one of the items for each row, correct?  I'm trying to put many items on one row of the ListView and keep track of where I'm at in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Put 4 textviews in your listview's layout and set their values like following getView() method from hashMap.
You can use first parameter of getView to get Position of selected item of listview.
If not want to print anything than set values as textview.setText("")

```
private List<HashMap<String, String>> myData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<HashMap<String, String>> objects)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        try 
        {
            context = getContext();
            myData = objects;
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View v = convertView;

    if(v == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_message_give_away_volunteers, null);
    }

    HashMap<String, String> hasValues = myData.get(position);

    if(hasValues != null)
    {

        TextView txt_VolunteerName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtVolunteerName);
        txt_VolunteerName.setText(hasValues.get(DatabaseConstant.key_USER_NAME));

        TextView txt_SkillLevel = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtSkillLevel);
        txt_SkillLevel.setText(hasValues.get(DatabaseConstant.key_SKILL_LEVEL));

    }
}
```